# Why don't I get a SocketException when my server application receives a RST packet?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I am wondering why my server application does not get a SocketException in case the client application, which receives the data the server is sending, has terminated before. A capture of the network traffic shows clearly that the client sends a FIN packet that is answered with an ACK packet by the server (1312 is the server port here):

```
Info
54434→1312 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=887691835 TSecr=0 WS=128
1312→54434 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2651623 TSecr=887691835
54434→1312 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=0 TSval=887691835 TSecr=2651623
54434→1312 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=12 TSval=887691836 TSecr=2651623
1312→54434 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=13 Win=66560 Len=0 TSval=2651645 TSecr=887691836
54434→1312 [FIN, ACK] Seq=13 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=0 TSval=887693987 TSecr=2651645
1312→54434 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=14 Win=66560 Len=0 TSval=2651839 TSecr=887693987
1312→54434 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=14 Win=66560 Len=3 TSval=2657624 TSecr=887693987
54434→1312 [RST] Seq=14 Win=0 Len=0
```

Hence the server should know that the client has closed his part of the stream to the server and isn't reading any more data. But the server application does not get a SocketException when it is either reading or writing to its ServerSocket.

Client:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(Util.getHost(), Util.getPort());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {
    String cmd = "sleep:" + sleepMillisToSend + "\n";
    writer.write(cmd);
    writer.flush();
    LOGGER.info("Terminated.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Server:

```
try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
    Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);) {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Received: " + inputLine);
            if (inputLine.startsWith(CMD_SLEEP)) {
                if (inputLine.length() > CMD_SLEEP.length()) {
                    String value = inputLine.substring(CMD_SLEEP.length());
                    try {
                        Long millis = Long.valueOf(value);
                        LOGGER.info("Sleeping for " + millis + "ms.");
                        Thread.sleep(millis);
                        writer.write("OK\n");
                        writer.flush();
                        break;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not convert " + value + " into a long.", e);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Thread was interrupted.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info("Terminated.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```